# Google Chrome keep loading mobile URL on desktop Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

I'm using Google Chrome `Version 53.0.2785.101 (64-bit)` on ASUS Laptop.
When I want to see some webs, browser keep loading mobile version like this:
[image]
I have tried to find the answer on Askubuntu or Google but sadly I have found nothing.
 Any help would be appreciate!

Comment: I doubt this issue is related to Ubuntu unless you have a local HTTP proxy that rewrites requests to trick the web site into thinking you're on a mobile browser. Of course such a proxy could also run on a different machine and your internet connection is to configured. Your internet provider may run such a proxy to intercept your connection transparently. Do you have a proxy configured or are you on a mobile internet connection? Alternatively, a browser add-on interferes to redirect you onto mobile pages.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I just a normal user without proxy. How can I get `User-Agent` field like you did?

Comment: @DavidFoerster My result same like you have. `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.101 Safari/537.36`

Comment: Does the issue occur in different browsers (e. g. Chromium, Firefox), with disabled add-ons, or in different browser profiles?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Amazing suggestion! The problem is `Data Saver` add-ons  did this.[Data Saver](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-saver/pfmgfdlgomnbgkofeojodiodmgpgmkac?hl=vi)

Comment: @DavidFoerster [Google Support](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392284?hl=vi) said `Data Saver` can be used in desktop.

Comment: David Forster's suggestion worked for me too. I had  a very similar issue as the OP and my issues began when I installed a Chrome extension called "XDM Helper". Removing it immediately fixed my issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to OP's comment, the culprit was the [Data Saver browser add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-saver/pfmgfdlgomnbgkofeojodiodmgpgmkac) that redirects page requests onto the mobile page versions, because they are (quite likely) smaller in data volume than their "desktop" counterparts.

Disabling the add-on fixed the issue.